# SQLite database select query from multiple tables for windows phone

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

Trying to develop a Windows phone 8.0 Store App.I need to retrieve records from a sqlite database which are having two tables so far i did not found any tutorial for it .here is what i am doing for get data from one table

```
var retrievedTasks = dbConn.Query<MMain>("SELECT MMain.ID,           MMain.Name, health.age
FROM MMain INNER JOIN health ON MMain.key = health.key
where MMain.ID = 1" ).FirstOrDefault();
```

but i want to achieve this to get data from two tables

```
       foreach (var rr in retrievedTasks)
        { 

         //how to fetch data from health class table 
        }
```

so how to do this and than how to fetch Data from it

he

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks wrong (one extra comma and you should use `INNER` join with the relevant ON clause)

```
SELECT MMain.ID, MMain.Name, health.age
FROM MMain INNER JOIN health ON MMain.key = health.key
where MMain.ID = 1
```

Apart that, I don't see the pb.